# Clang Installation in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, clang

I am trying for a couple of days to download & install Clang (my Operating System is Windows).

For this, I opened my Visual Studio -> new -> project -> cross platform -> install Clang.

After the installation finished I opened a new C++ file and I got errors on every use of Clang. For example,

- "name must be a namespace name" on "using namespace clang;"
- "cannot open source file 'clang/Driver/Options.h'"

So, how should I use it correctly in Viusal Studio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you expecting, the Clang extension of VS provides? Show the code you have, that produces the errors.

Comment: Do you want to cross compile for mobile devices, or use clang for Windows apps? In the latter case, run setup again and select "Clang with Microsoft CodeGen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Clang this way does not neccessarrily give you the headers for libclang, as they are not technically needed.
The missing header also explains why the namespace is not found.

When you install Clang through Visual Studio you will most likely just get the compiler so you can compile your code with clang instead of cl.

That said not even the pre-built binary releases for windows from [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html)
contain the header you try to include.
So you may have more luck by downloading the source and manually compiling the components you need.

Comment: So I need to dowload the source of Clang from you link? OK, I downloaded it now. It's a *.src.tar.xz file. I extracted it using 7-zip and then I did untar. Now what should I do to make Visual Studio aware of this source?

Comment: The Clang source contains an "include" directory at top level. Add this to your project include paths (project settings -> c/c++ -> general -> additional include directories).
The names of the menu entries might differ slightly as I use the German version fo MSVC.

Anyways, doing this will most likely result in linker errors,
unless all the code you use is header-only. So you will need to read the LLVM/Clang documentation to find out how to compile the libraries you might need.